# Cannot install pythontex

Tags: installing, windows, python, texmf

I have been trying to install `pythontex` on Windows 8 (64-bit) with `MiKTeX` installed.

- I have tried running "latex pythontex.ins" from the directory but it doesn't work.
- I have tried using the package manager but pythontex is not there.
- I have tried running "tlpkg install pythontex" but it seems its not installed.
- I have tried running "python pythontex_install_texlive.py" from the directory but it complains that it      cannot find TEXMF.

Please Help :(

Comment: Are you using the [latest version](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/blob/master/pythontex/pythontex_install_texlive.py) of the install script? An earlier version had a bug that prevented it from requesting manual entry of a path, in the event that TEXMF cannot be found. Also, does `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFDIST` work for you on the command line?

Comment: Here is a screenshot it that helps 
http://i.imgur.com/iTWPdC3.jpg

Comment: hi G.Poore, Firstly Thanks for creating pythontex :) and i was thinking of sending u an email. I used the version available on github.

Comment: running kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFDIST returns c:\Program Files\MiKeTeX 2.9

Comment: Have you tried manually entering a path after you get to that step in the install script? If you don't already have a directory for manually installing packages, you could take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows.

Comment: So i followed the link and made a TDS and ran your script again and it ran successfully ! however as you can see latex still doesnt identify pythontex
[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/XNP3gCh.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Your package manager is showing the `python` package, which is different from `pythontex`.  You may need to tell your package manager to update its database (or run `mktexlsr` on the command line).  Once that is done, I would expect things to work.  Keep in mind that compiling will be a three-step process:  run LaTeX, run `pythontex <file>`, run LaTeX again.  If your `C:\textmf\bin` isn't on your PATH, you will need to add it so that `pythontex.exe` can be found (`pythontex.exe` should have been created in that location).

Comment: Yeah, your documentation is really clear about how to use pythontex, however getting it up and running is whats posing some difficulty :(. I couldnt find pythontex.exe in the bin folder so i ran your script again, apparently i need something called as runscript.exe http://i.imgur.com/yDwVkqH.jpg

Comment: I ran `mktexlsr`, and also updated the package manager using the GUI. no luck :(

Comment: `runscript.exe` is for TeX Live, so you may not have it. (If you did, it might be somewhere under `c:\Program Files\MiKeTeX 2.9`, probably in a `bin` directory.) You could take the sample `pythontex.bat` and edit it so that it has the right path to `pythontex.py`, then put it in the `bin` directory.

Comment: I also did what the error message says. but it cannot find the correct script file http://i.imgur.com/6arwLv7.png. Should i copy the .bat file into the `script` directory or should i copy the scripts it needs into the `bin` directory ?

Comment: Its trivial to copy the files i needs and change the windows PATH variable.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PltBpTB.jpg
I edited the `bat` file and now `pythontex` works from the `cmd`. it still doesnt show up in the package manager but are you sure that this is fine ? can i just pass in the `.tex` file into `pythontex` from `cmd` or `bash` and things will work, without latex not registering it in the package manager :(

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KgTH19B.jpg
I think i am really close ! `latex` recognizes pythontex.sty also i am able to run `pythontex` from the `cmd` on `<file>.tex` however no `.dvi` is produced. The thing is i usually dont use `.dvi` i prefer directly outputing to pdf using `pdflatex`. Can i run `pdflatex` instead of `latex`.

Comment: also the way to use `pythontex` is 
- `latex <filename>.tex`
- `pythontex <filename>.tex` 
- `latex <filename>.tex`
am i correct ?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/BLG453b.jpg
Also `PythonTex`is complaining. It just hello world :(

Comment: `pdflatex` is fine...it's what I usually use.  You are getting an error because by default PythonTeX imports the `print()` function from `__future__`.  If you don't want that, then `\usepackage[pyfuture=none]{pythontex}`

Comment: Yes It finally Works !! :D